# Central Processing System gets Hot

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, cooling, temperature

I have an Intel Desktop Board with an Intel Pentium D processor installed.
My problem is that the processor stays warm when idle i.e. 55 degrees C . But under load the temperature rises drastically i.e. a scorching 76 degrees C.Similarly the CPU Heat Sink Fan spins extremely fast thus emitting a lot of noise.

I have well applied the thermal paste (Silicon Thermal Tape) but no improvements.I had noticed the v12 voltage operating at v10.55. This situation had been for quite sometime. Until then i borrowed my friends Intel Dual Core processor and installed it.

To my surprise it worked well with temperatures at 37 degrees C both at idle & load time.Similarly the v12 voltage improved and operated at v11.88 
So my question is that is it the fault of the processor entirely or some other fault regarding the motherboard or PSU voltages. 
Similarly if i need to change the processor then suggest me a gaming processor 3.00 GHz and above.

My Computer Specs are

- Intel D945GCCR Motherboard with 800 Mhz FSB,
- Intel 945 Chipset,
- Intel Pentium D 945 Presler CPU, 3.4 GHZ, 4MB L2 cache, 800 MHz in an LGA 775 Socket,
- Nvidia Geforce 7600 GS Graphics,
- 2 GB DDR2 SDRAM,
- 500 GB Internal HDD.

The Dual core processor I tried was a  Intel Pentium Dual Core E5700 Wolfdale CPU ,3.0GHz,
2MB L2 cache,800 MHz.

Comment: Still using the stock fan? I'd make sure that it spins up and doesn't make any strange noises. Replacing the fan with something more robust will do MOUNDS for cooling.

Comment: There are huge design and physical differences between a Intel Dual Core processor and a  Pentium D.  You cannot compare to the two.

Comment: Is 76C a bad temperature for a processor? My Macbook (yeah not a Pentium D, but still a CPU made from silicon) always ran at 60c without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Ambient temperature can be high for several reasons, but one could be simply that your case isn't moving the hot air off the chips very efficiently. With air-cooled systems, you have to make sure that airflow is good. If you don't feel hot air ventilating out the back of your case, then that tells me that you might have a heat pocket in there. It could be due to turbulence (if you have multiple fans blowing air in many directions), it could be because of cabling getting in the way of the airflow, or other reasons.

Make sure that when your internal components are laid out that you pay close attention to how the fans are installed, what direction they're pushing air, and that air channels and exhaust vents are clear of obstruction. This should fix your issues (it fixed mine when I was dealing with the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

There are huge design and physical differences between a Intel Dual Core processor and a Pentium D. You cannot compare to the two.  One requires more voltage then the other for one.  More voltage means it runs hotter.

I should point out if everything about your system is at stock then those temperatures are normal.  Your friend's Intel Dual Core processor is suppose to run cooler then your processor.  Unless your system is crashing you shouldn't attempt to fix a problem that doesn't exist.

I should add the socket your motherboard uses has been disconinued.  There isn't a replacement that will run cooler that is compatible with your motherboard.